# Export data in a txt file using PowerShell

Tags: csv, powershell

I’m working in a text file which is going to be exported to show in a database and generate reports.

This text file was created by parsing a trace what the customers tune in the set-top boxes of a company where I work. The structure of each line is below:

Last Channel Tuned:

```
2016-05-10 22:30:19.282417 ; 10.193.115.63 ; 148.240.175.37 ;Data-- {"preferences":[{"key":"tv.mirada.iptv.navi.lastChannelTuned","value":"THC","basis":"DEVICE"}]} --
```

Last Channel Tuned and Last Volume:

```
2016-05-10 22:30:19.366016 ; 10.25.60.54 ; 148.240.175.37 ;Data-- {"preferences":[{"key":"tv.mirada.iptv.navi.lastVolume","value":12,"basis":"DEVICE"},{"key":"tv.mirada.iptv.navi.lastChannelTuned","value":"QROESTRELLA","basis":"DEVICE"}]} --
```

Last Channel Tuned and Surf Mode:

```
2016-05-10 22:30:19.953626 ; 10.85.156.3 ; 148.240.175.37 ;Data-- {"preferences":[{"key":"tv.mirada.iptv.navi.lastChannelTuned","value":"TFLMZN","basis":"DEVICE"},{"key":"tv.mirada.iptv.navi.surfMode","value":"ALL","basis":"DEVICE"}]} --
```

Last Channel Tuned, Last Volume and Surf Mode:

```
2016-05-10 22:30:48.651843 ; 10.193.158.74 ; 148.240.175.37 ;Data-- {"preferences":[{"key":"tv.mirada.iptv.navi.lastVolume","value":16,"basis":"DEVICE"},{"key":"tv.mirada.iptv.navi.lastChannelTuned","value":"NICK","basis":"DEVICE"},{"key":"tv.mirada.iptv.navi.surfMode","value":"ALL","basis":"DEVICE"}]} ––
```

I would like to show this data in a “database” which contains the next “attributes”:

-Date

-IP source

-IP destination

-Channel Tuned

[Database Channel Tuned in CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIwGi.png)

I use PowerShell to do this automatically. I’m new in PowerShell. Then, I want this information transformed in a CSV file.

Any idea?

Regards.

Comment: There are many examples of filtering text files and outputting to CSV in powershell. Since you're new to powershell start with searching for those and adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in semicolon delimited format.  This mean's we can use PowerShell's `ConvertFrom-CSV` cmdlet to parse the data for us :)

I stored one of your records as the variable `$e` for a proof of concept.

```
$e = '2016-05-10 22:30:19.282417 ; 10.193.115.63 ; 148.240.175.37 ;Data-- {"preferences":[{"key":"tv.mirada.iptv.navi.lastChannelTuned","value":"THC","basis":"DEVICE"}]} --'
$e | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'Date','SourceIP','DestIP','Data' -Delimiter ';'
```

and the output

```
Date                        SourceIP       DestIP          Data                                                                                                     
----                        --------       ------          ----                                                                                                     
2016-05-10 22:30:19.282417  10.193.115.63  148.240.175.37  Data-- {"preferences":[{"key":"tv.mirada.iptv.navi.lastChannelTuned","value":"THC","basis":"DEVICE"}]} --
```

Now you can easily export this in any sort of file format you'd like!

Comment: Very good. Well, now I have the Data attribute, I want to extract the channel (for example: THC, QROESTRELLA, TFLMZN, NICK) and show the Channel atribute instead of Data atribute in the same table. I shared an image where it is the "database". It is possible?

Comment: The data property is in json format, so if you use the convertfrom-json cmdlet you should be able to get the channel out. Don't forget to up vote and mark as answer if this helped you get closer to solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I found a way to extract partially that property. With this code, how to "mix" this with a lot of events? I put an answer with the code, the output and the image.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
Clear-Host
$Input = @"

{
"preferences": [
{ "key":"tv.mirada.iptv.navi.lastChannelTuned" , "value":"THC" , "basis":"DEVICE" }
  ]
}

"@

$Victim = $Input | ConvertFrom-JSON
$Victim.preferences | Format-Table value -AutoSize
```

Output:

```
value
-----
THC
```

Image: [Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKbxv.png)